# JQuery Dialog not opening in browser

Tags: c#, jquery, html

```
          <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" /> 
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script> 


     <script type="text/javascript"> 
     function getalert1(Leave_RegisterID) 
            {
                document.getElementById('<%= hdnLeave_RegID.ClientID %>').value = Leave_RegisterID;
                $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
                $(function () {
                    $('#reason').dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        show: "blind",
                        hide: "explode",
                        display: ''
                    });
                    $('.LeaveReason1').click(function () 
                    {
                        $('#reason').html();
                        $('#reason').dialog('open');
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            }
</script>
```

The Button that i click :

```
      <button id="LeaveReason1" class="LeaveReason1" onclick="getalert1('<%# Eval("Leave_RegisterID") %>');" title="Decline">Decline</button>
```

However when i debug in firebug it does not got inside this code which it should :

```
   $('#reason').html();
   $('#reason').dialog('open');
   return false;
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="reason" style="height: 300px; min-height: 109px; width: auto; display:none;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content"   runat="server">   
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
                <tr>
                    <td width="25%" class="body_txt" style="padding-right:2px">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblReason" runat="server" Text="Reason:" ></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td width="75%">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtReason" Height="40%" Width="100%" MaxLength="200" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" CssClass="txt_bx" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <asp:Button Width="30%" runat="server" Text="Submit" id="btnSubmit" Height="25px" CssClass="clButton" ></asp:Button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: You did not write the function inside <script></script> tag. Is this error in your original code?

Answer (score 0):

it does not go inside the above given code.. since you have that code inside another click event..so basically for that to work you have to click the same button again.... which will not work..

try this

```
  function getalert1(Leave_RegisterID)  // you are calling this function whn click
    {
        document.getElementById('<%= hdnLeave_RegID.ClientID %>').value = Leave_RegisterID;
        $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
         //$(function () { and no need of ready function here
            $('#reason').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: "blind",
                hide: "explode",
                display: ''
            });

           // $('.LeaveReason1').click(function () {  again you have a click event here which is not necessary at all.. since the click is already fired by  getalert1()
                $('#reason').html();

                $('#reason').dialog('open');
                return false;

        });
    }
```

Comment: debug it and see....`console.log('here')` inside `getalert11()` and check if it is getting inside the function... let me know...

Comment: Yes it comes inside the function. It moves through the whole function but the page just refreshes in the end

Comment: so there is something else that is refreshing the page..please check your code... dialog is not seen because of that refresh ..

Comment: <button id="LeaveReason1" class="LeaveReason1" onclick="getalert1('<%# Eval("Leave_RegisterID") %>'); return false;"
                                    title="Decline">
                                    Decline</button>

Comment: I did something like this the page does not refresh but no popup is displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//separate your dialog init
$(function() {
    $('#reason').dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         show: "blind",
         hide: "explode"
    });
});

//only have one click event
$('.LeaveReason1').click(function () 
                {
        document.getElementById('<%= hdnLeave_RegID.ClientID %>').value = Leave_RegisterID;
                $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;

                    $('#reason').html();
                    $('#reason').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });
```

Comment: but i am calling this function on button click why to put it inside document.ready

Comment: just making sure. document.ready triggers when everything in the page is loaded. we don't want to assign a click event to something that does not exist yet. but that's not the focus here, just got use to doing that..